# display only variable names in stacked correlation matrix in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS, is there a way to display the variable label instead of the variable name in a stacked correlation matrix? Specifically in the row that goes across at the top of the matrix? I'm applying a template that modifies base.corr.stackedmatrix, changing the color of significant p-values to red, and I know using RowLabel for the column displays the variable label. I can't figure out how to display the label for the row of variable names so only the variable labels are displayed.

```
proc format;
    value pvalsig low-.05 ="red" .05-high="black";
run;

proc template;
    edit base.corr.stackedmatrix;
        column (RowLabel) (Matrix) * (Matrix2) * (Matrix3) * (Matrix4);
        edit matrix2;
            style={foreground=pvalsig.};
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Can you post some code, preferably so we can replicate the issue and help work it out?

Comment: @Reeza Below is the code: 

proc format;
    value pvalsig low-.05 ="red"  
                 .05-high="black";
run;  
  
proc template; 
   edit base.corr.stackedmatrix; 
      column (RowLabel) (Matrix) * (Matrix2) * (Matrix3) * (Matrix4); 
      edit matrix2 ;  
         style={foreground=pvalsig.};  
      end;
    end; 
run;

Before, RowName was included with RowLabel, which displayed the variable name and label, so I removed it to only display the variable label. However, it doesn't change the row at the top of the correlation matrix, just the left-hand column.

Comment: @Reeza I tried to edit my comment to better format the code, but it didn't seem to work...